# how to write a sorting method to return max Element without modifing the original array

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, sorting, stack

Have tried creaing a stack class with push,pop and getmax function, however using sorting on even the temp variable is modifying the original, array please suggest where have i gone wrong.

```
  constructor() {
    this.dataArr = [];
    this.size = 0;
  }
  insert(data) {
    this.dataArr.push(data);
    this.size++;
  }
//this function is modifying original dataArr of stack
  getMax() {
    let temp = this.dataArr;
    let val = temp.sort((a, b) => {
      return b - a;
    })[0];
    return val;
  }
  pop() {
    this.dataArr.shift();
    this.size--;
  }
}

let s1 = new Stack();

s1.insert(1);
s1.insert(44);
s1.insert(1);
s1.insert(19);
s1.insert(17);

console.log(s1);//Stack { dataArr: [ 1, 44, 1, 19, 17, 19 ], size: 6 }

console.log(s1.getMax());//returns 44 

console.log(s1);//returns Stack { dataArr: [ 44, 19, 19, 17, 1, 1 ], size: 6 }

s1.pop()

console.log(s1.getMax());//returns 19
//wakjbckjsbck

console.log(s1);//Stack { dataArr: [ 19, 19, 17, 1, 1 ], size: 5 }
```

Comment: You have to make a copy of the array, not just assign to another variable.

Comment: You don't need to sort the array to get the highest value.

Comment: thanks a lot @Barmar , deep copying did the trick 
  getMax() {
    let temp = [...this.dataArr];
    let val = temp.sort((a, b) => {
      return b - a;
    })[0];
    return val;
  }